# setTimeout in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

here is one sample code I have:

```
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
    var cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
    cx.beginPath();


    for (var y = 0; y < 500; y+=10) {
        cx.moveTo(0,0);
        cx.lineTo(500,y);
    }

    cx.lineWidth = 3;
    cx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    cx.stroke();

</script>
```

It creates 50 lines start from one point. I want to use `setTimeout` for each line. So I thought the code below should do the work but it's not working:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    for (var y = 0; y < 500; y+=10) {
        cx.moveTo(0,0);
        cx.lineTo(500,y);
        cx.stroke();
    }
}, 300);
```

could someone please tell me what is the problem

Comment: put the timeout in the loop and use a wrapper function to close y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbu6c4hw/)

#### HTML:

```
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var start = 0;
var leftX = start;
var leftY = start;
var end = 500;
var cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
cx.beginPath();
cx.lineWidth = 3;
cx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

for (y = start; y < end; y++) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        cx.moveTo(start, start);
        cx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
        cx.stroke();
        leftX++;
        leftY++;
    }, 1 + (y * 20) / 3);
}
```

Comment: just curios: why  "window.setTimeout"? (instead of just setTimeout)

Comment: Well, it doesn't make any difference and I like to use it this way. :)

Comment: fair enough. it does run slower and is more to type, but yeah, it makes no diff in output. you can use window.window.window.setTimeout too. i see "window" a lot in front of _location_, but if they're calling getComputedStyle(),  for some reason it's document.defaultView.getComputedStyle instead of window.getComputedStyle or just getComputedStyle... anyways, i was just curious if there was a convention or reason to be explicit like that, thanks for replying.